# Send an image to the background

Tags: graphics, backgrounds

I have a image on a page, and the whitespace creeps onto the header and covers it.

I realise I could make the image smaller, or crop some of the whitespace on the original image, but I have lots of images in the document that do this.

Is there a command which allows me to tell me header to be at the "front" and the image at the "back"?

### Edit

My headers are added, using the fancyhdr package this way:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\leftmark}
```

The images that I'm talking about are all of this format:

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=230mm]{pic1.png}
\caption{}
\label{template}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and show the way you include the image and how the header is set? There are some possibilities but they depend on how you work with the images. The best solution would be to crop the images, though. E.g. you can use Photoshop to automate this …

Comment: You could also use imagemagic or similar to replace the white in the image by transparent

Comment: width=\textheight is as big as you should go.

Comment: You can put the `\leftmark` in the footer (which is printed after the textbody) and raise it: `\fancyfoot[Re,LO]{\raisebox{\dimexpr\textheight+\footskip+\headsep+\dp\strutbox\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\leftmark}}`.

Comment: On Windows, you could use IrfanView to crop whitespace away from images in a batch mode. [One guide for installing and batch resizing is here](http://www.maximumpc.com/irfanview-batch-resize-images-2014/), but the only difference would be to use "Auto crop borders" instead of resizing in Step 8.

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Perhaps `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` would work for you. Requires `graphicx` and `eso-pic`, I believe. My own setup is very different from yours, so "works for me" might differ from "works for you." The catch with this method is that you would have to know exactly how the image is placed absolutely on the page, rather than how it is placed in-line in the text. The underlying issue is that PDF writes objects in the order they are created. so an (opaque) image can block earlier text, yet underlay later text.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use package `scrlayer-scrpage` instead `fancyhdr` you can print the page header in foreground using

```
\usepackage[automark,pagestyleset=standard]{scrlayer-scrpage}[2015/07/02]
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}

\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{\ModifyLayer[foreground]{#1}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[automark,pagestyleset=standard]{scrlayer-scrpage}[2015/07/02]
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}

\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{\ModifyLayer[foreground]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}
  \begin{center}
    \makebox[\textheight]{\includegraphics[width=230mm]{example-image.png}}
    \caption{}
    \label{template}
  \end{center}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
\end{document}
```